# How can I resolve this Leaflet error? getPixelWorldBounds()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, proj4js

Does anyone know what could be causing the following error when trying to create a leaflet map? It has something to do with the custom CRS. I can't post much of the code for various reasons so if someone can point me in the right direction, I will greatly appreciate it.

**this._map.getPixelWorldBounds() is null**

```
L.map(containerId, {
    maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(-90, -180), L.latLng(90,180)),
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 1,
    center: centerLatLng,
    zoom: 2,
    crs: getCrs(),
    worldCopyJump: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false
});

function getCrs() {
    return new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:4326', '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs', {
        origin: [-180, 90],
        tileSize: 512,
        resolutions: [...]
    });
}
//Removed resolutions for brevity.
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: thanks. I can't get to that site at the moment - but i will check it out as soon as I can. I did change my getCrs() to  L.CRS.EPSG4326 and it fixed the error. I guess I need to check that custom function to see why its causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue adding EPSG:32661 support to Leaflet by using [Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize' of null
    at NewClass._onZoomEnd (leaflet-src.js?8af6:13235)
    at NewClass.whenReady (leaflet-src.js?8af6:4450)
    at NewClass.addHooks (leaflet-src.js?8af6:13157)
    at NewClass.enable (leaflet-src.js?8af6:5722)
    at NewClass.addHandler (leaflet-src.js?8af6:3736)
    at NewClass.init (leaflet-src.js?8af6:385)
    at NewClass.proto.callInitHooks (leaflet-src.js?8af6:357)
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js?8af6:3148)
    at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js?8af6:301)
    at Map.createLeafletElement (Map.js?fe6c:87)
```

I found that the issue is raised by usage of `worldCopyJump`. By removing it the error disappear.